# Run spring boot without @SpringBootApplication annotation as jar library in another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use @autowired annotation in a spring boot project that's not started by main method with @SpringBootApplication annotation. Instead, i did created a jar of that spring project and i'm using that jar as an external jar in a legacy project (non-spring project).
As result i can't get ApplicationContext and all beans managed by spring when you run application from main method are null.

Is that possible to use Spring boot project as a .jar without run main method??

```
public class RetrieveSubscriberType {
    public RetrieveSubscriberType() {
        ApplicationContext appCtx = ApplicationContextUtils
                .getApplicationContext();
        
        this.subscriber = (SubscriberDAOImpl)appCtx.getBean("subscriber");
    }
```

appCtx always null

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {   
    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

      @Override
      public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext)
          throws BeansException {
        ctx = appContext;

      }

      public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
      }
}
```

ApplicationContextUtils where method setApplicationContext is not called

Comment: The `@Autowired` annotation is part of the spring framework, not SpringBoot (which uses it, as you know) - you should not have an issue with using it in a legacy app.  See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_autowired_annotation.htm

Comment: ok, but i 'dont have a Beans.xml file and my @Configuration annotation class, does not get called, since i not running it from main method. Is just a jar where i try to instantiate a class with autowired properties

Comment: Without specifics, I'd be guessing as what you have to do. Your question was: is it possible? and the answer (and link) indicate that yes, it is.  The `@Configuration` annotation needs to be registered into the context, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Comment: Please add an example of how you try and get `ApplicationContext` in the legacy application.

Comment: @Aivaras i'm not trying to get ApplicatioContext in legacy. But actually in the spring project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

You might need to bootstrap your `@Configuration` classes via `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`

`@Configuration` classes are typically bootstrapped using either `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` or its web-capable variant, `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`.

A simple example with the former follows:

```
 AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
 ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
 ctx.refresh();
 MyBean myBean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
 // use myBean ...
```

Comment: @user353089 glad I could help :) - and no, I am not a genius, just getting good at reading documentation ;)